# "Rotating" to get AVL Tree

Tags: rotation, avl-tree

Why is the process of balancing to get an AVL tree called **rotation**? (While you are at it, what's **single** & **double** rotation?)

Every textbook of mine blatantly uses that word without any explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a operation of changing root in sub-tree of your tree, this is very simple operation and this can not be explained (because is simple).

[image]

Comment: Nice diagrams.  Don't forget the OP asks about the difference between single and double rotations.

Answer (score 1):

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_rotation).

Comment: The wiki article on AVL trees is awful, BTW.  If you want to understand what they are and how they work, it's useless.  If you want to know what they are -and you already know-, it's perfect.